# I can't call my image to add it to my screen

Tags: python-3.x

I learned if I wanted to add an image to my screen I either have to

1. write down the location of the image and assign it to a variable
2. add it to the screen with `screen.addshape`(variable)

**or**

1. place the image in the file my code is located
2. use `d:\\imagename.imagetype` to assign the image to a variable
3. then use `screen.addshape`

this is the code I've written:

```
    import turtle
    import random


    /*this is the part I'm having trouble with*/

    screen=turtle.Screen()
    image1="E:\대학 과제\파이썬\코드\08\\rabbit.gif"  
    image2="E:\대학 과제\파이썬\코드\08\\turtle.gif"
    screen.addshape(image1)
    screen.addshape(image2)

    t1=turtle.Turtle()
    t1.shape(image2)
    t1.pensize(5)
    t1.penup()
    t1.goto(-300,0)

    t2=turtle.Turtle()
    t2.shape(image1)
    t2.pensize(5)
    t2.penup()
    t2.goto(-300,-200)
```

but none of these work and I get an error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1133, in register_shape
>       shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
>     File "C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 479, in _image
>       return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
>     File "C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 3545, in **init**
>       Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
>     File "C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 3501, in **init**
>       self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
>   _tkinter.TclError